# Gradle unable to resolve dynamic version of plugin from mavenLocal, how to get latest version?

Tags: gradle

I have created a Gradle plugin that creates some extra tasks and am publishing the plugin to MavenLocal with version 0.2.1.  I can see the created jar in `~/.m2`.

In another Gradle project, I am trying to pull in that plugin within the `buildscript` section of `build.gradle`, like this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.example:myplugin:0.2.+'
    }
}
```

Running `gradle tasks` (or any other task, for that matter) causes Gradle to fail with the message:

```
> Plugin with id 'com.example.myplugin' not found.
```

However, if I change the version from `0.2.+` to `0.2.1` then it works.  How do I get the latest version of the plugin into my project?

Comment: what is the gradle/gradlew version do you use, I tried myself, it works for me.

Comment: and you should use gradle composite build if possible to test your plugin.

Comment: @chenrui what do you mean by grade composite build please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just put what I did in here, and hope it helps you.

For example, I install the [gradle-tomcat-plugin](https://github.com/bmuschko/gradle-tomcat-plugin) locally (2.4.1 and 2.4.2).

```
$ git checkout v2.4.2
$ ./gradlew publishToMavenLocal
$ git checkout v2.4.1
$ ./gradlew publishToMavenLocal
$ ls /Users/ruichen/.m2/repository/com/bmuschko/gradle-tomcat-plugin
2.4.1                    maven-metadata-local.xml
2.4.2
```

And I added a separate task (`showClasspath`) to `build.gradle` to show me what is the version got applied:

```
task showClasspath {
    doLast {
        buildscript.configurations.classpath.each { println it.name }
    }
}
```

The `buildscript` block is also pretty much like yours:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.bmuschko:gradle-tomcat-plugin:2.4.+"
    }
}
```

The output is expected:

```
$ ./gradlew showClasspath

> Task :showClasspath
gradle-tomcat-plugin-2.4.2.jar
```

Comment: Thanks for confirming, I ended up needing to re-run with `--refresh-dependencies` which seemed to force my setup to respect the dependency.